How to expose multiple container ports to traefik
After keycloak v25 release they removed /health path and added management port 9000 instead. i am using keycloak in docker-compose:
version: '3.3'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.1
    volumes:
      - ./export:/tmp/export
      - ./export:/opt/keycloak/data/import
      - ./java.config:/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config
    environment:
      - *some env vars*
      - "KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true"
    expose:
      - 8080
    networks:
      - web
    command: start-dev
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.rule=Host(`id.mydomain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls.certresolver=letsEncrypt"
      - "traefik.http.services.keycloak-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
networks:
  web:
    external: true

i tried to add additional traefik labels and expose port 9000 but then id.mydomain.com leads to management port instead:
version: '3.3'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.1
    volumes:
      - ./export:/tmp/export
      - ./export:/opt/keycloak/data/import
      - ./java.config:/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config
    environment:
      - *some env vars*
      - "KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true"
    expose:
      - 8080
      - 9000         #THIS
    networks:
      - web
    command: start-dev
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.rule=Host(`id.mydomain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls.certresolver=letsEncrypt"
      - "traefik.http.services.keycloak-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
#AND THIS
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-health.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-health.rule=Host(`id.mydomain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/health`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-health.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-health.tls.certresolver=letsEncrypt"
      - "traefik.http.services.keycloak-health-service.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"

networks:
  web:
    external: true

any suggestions on how can i configure this to work properly?

after a long search i have found a solution here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1150277/traefik-routing-to-two-ports-in-one-docker-container
long story short the services should be named explicitly in case you need multiple ports for a container. in my case i neede to add two strings:
      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.service=keycloak"

      - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak-health.service=keycloak-health"

